# How can I know if an IaC Azure resource requires a certain name without running a deployment and it failing?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

Sometimes I'll add a resource to my Bicep and it'll fail because the name is incorrect.

For example, a VM shutdown schedule:

```yaml
resource vmAutoShutdown 'Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules@2018-09-15' = {
  name: '${vm.name}-autoshutdown'
  location: location
  //<snip>
}
```

That name isn't allowed - it has to be `'shutdown-computevm-${vm.name}'`

Or virus scanning for an Azure Blob Storage container:

```yaml
resource defenderForStorageSettings 'Microsoft.Security/DefenderForStorageSettings@2022-12-01-preview' = if (enableVirusScanning)  {
  name: '${storage.name}-antivirus'
  scope: storage
  //<snip>
}
```

Nope, must be `name: 'current'`.

Is there a way to find this out or validate the names that doesn't require running an actual deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, there is no easy way to know in my experience. What I usually do is check the Azure Template Reference for the specific Azure resource I want to deploy, You can easily find all the available options for the Azure resources in Bicep, ARM, and Terraform from this documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/

Then I also refer to the Azure Resource Name rules documentation to understand different naming requirements for each service I use. There are various restrictions depending on the service you use. You can find the Azure resource naming rules and restrictions in this documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules

Comment: Accepting this answer for now. The second link is probably the closest I'll get to a comprehensive answer at the moment, but I hope there'll be something better in the future.

Comment: Yeah, As of now it's up to us to know the restrictions of different Azure services. I would love to see this implemented as part of the template validation process. That would make things so much easier.